# How to impersonate a GoogleCredential in a google apps domain?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm making an application wich allows the admin to manage the files of users in the google apps domain.
Since the docList api is deprecated I used the Drive api.

***How I can create a Drive service as another user while  logged in as admin?***

Some people suggested to use the OAuth consumer key.

But I don't know how to implement this with oauth-2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this post: [Google Drive service account returns 403 usageLimits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503437/google-drive-service-account-returns-403-usagelimits/12526286#12526286)

I used OAuth2 and a service account to accomplish pretty much the same. Keep in mind you need to use the API Console to setup your environment and ensure the service account is added to the Google Apps domain with the proper scopes to allow access.

Comment: So I have to be domain admin to create this service account?

Comment: I would definitely help to be admin or have an admin involved because you need to do some settings in the admin panel to authorize the app. You can create the app and configure the console as a user.

Comment: I just did a quick check on a recent project. In that we have the appspot service account as a project member in the API console.